# Is an expression like "work upgrading" a correct construction?

Tags: grammar

> We also launched initiatives to put people to ***work upgrading*** our homes, businesses, and factories so that they waste less energy.

The expression *work upgrading* confuses me a little. Does the word *work* have an expression of the form *work doing something*? Why does the word *upgrading* use the form *doing* instead of *to do*?

Comment: I've come across similar construction. `Pass this jobs bill, and we can put people to work rebuilding America.` `We can put people to work building and rebuilding schools and fixing our roads and bridges.`

Answer (score 4):

*Work* and *upgrading* do not go together here; they should be parsed as

> [to put people to work] [upgrading our homes, businesses, and factories]

To *put sb to work* or *set sb to work* is to give them work to do, as Macmillan has it, from the use of *[put](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/put)* to mean

> to cause someone or something to be in a particular situation or state
>
> e.g. put someone to work: *He was put to work filing all the papers.*

The phrase introduced by *upgrading* describes the nature of the work to be done.